# Postgres: change primary key in existing table

Tags: postgresql

I have a situation with two tables where one has a foreign key pointing to the other table (simplified) schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(name)
); 

CREATE TABLE table2 (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   table1_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL REFERENCES table1(name)
);
```

Now I regret using the `name` column as primary key in `table1` - and would like to add integer serial key instead. Since I already have data in the database I guess I need to do this carefully. My current plan is as follows:

1. Drop the foreign key constraint: `table2(name)` with `ALTER TABLE table2 DROP CONSTRAINT table2_table1_name_fkey;`
2. Drop the primary key constraint on `table1(name)` with `ALTER TABLE table1 DROP CONSTRAINT name_pkey;`.
3. Add a unique constraint on `table1(name)` with `ALTER TABLE table1 ADD UNIQUE(name);`
4. Add a automatic primary key to `table1` with `ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;`.
5. Add a new column `table1_id` to `table2` with `ALTER TABLE table2 ADD COLUMN table1_id INT;`
6. Update all rows in `table2` - so that the new column (which will be promoted to a foreign key) gets the correct value - as inferred by the previous (still present) foreign key `table1_name`.

I have completed steps up to an including step 5, but the `UPDATE` (with `JOIN`?) required to complete 6 is beyond my SQL paygrade. My current (google based ...) attempt looks like:

```
UPDATE
  table2
SET
  table2.table1_id = t1.id
FROM
  table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2
     ON t2.table1_name = t1.name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `JOIN` in `UPDATE`.

```sql
UPDATE 
  table2 t2
SET
  table1_id = t1.id
FROM
  table1 t1
WHERE 
  t2.table1_name = t1.name;
```